# Having trouble with Japanese character "〜" in Android

Tags: android

I don't know how to read Japanese - I don't know what this character means.

We are using encoding UTF-8 in our XML file and can see all other Japanese characters in our app except for "〜", which shows up as a box. "〜" shows up in Eclipse, tried replacing it with a tilde (~), but the tilde is smaller and looks slightly different (〜 vs ~) in our app.

On Google Translate, it interprets the character as a tilde http://translate.google.com/#ja/en/%E3%80%9C

In Android, we have used &#12316; and \u301C but they both show up as boxes.

An example of how the character is used "気分が悪いよ〜！"

---

My question: This is the only character that's missing for us (we have an American Android phones and changed the language to Japanese). How do we make this character show up?

Comment: Perhaps the font is *not* capable of rendering it under Android...

Comment: I'm starting to think that that is the case. ~_~ I tried changing the encoding to "Android's guaranteed-available charsets" (ISO-8859-1, US-ASCII, UTF-16, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE). The first 2 wouldn't map, and the last 3 did not solve the issue. =(

Comment: Here is someone [talking about it (in Japanese)](http://waka8s.com/archives/android-wave-dash-fullwidth-tilda/) - it seems that there are issues, so perhaps you could replace it with a full-width tilde `U+FF5E`? The `U+301C` also seems to be upside down on Android.

Comment: Some further investigation - copy-pasting your 〜 above [into this page](http://rishida.net/tools/conversion/) gives me the `U+301C` you mention, but typing in a "real" ～ through the IME gives me `U+FF5E`. Furthermore, on Windows `U+301C` draws like a bitmapped font, but `U+FF5E` looks like a real True Type character. I think the problem might be your source files?

Comment: (To also answer your question below), I copied/pasted the U+301C version from our translator's version. The U+FF5E version is the same as the tilde (~), which is a smaller version of the wave dash, so it'll be our backup plan, but the character is noticeably smaller compared to other texts. Thanks for the link about the upside wave dash. We also don't have a pure Japanese phone to be able to realize that. >_<

Comment: There's no such thing as a "pure Japanese phone" AFAIK - it's the same distribution for all languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there are two similar characters in Unicode. First, we have `U+301C WAVE DASH`, [described here](http://codepoints.net/U+301C), then we have `U+FF5E FULLWIDTH TILDE`, [described here](http://codepoints.net/U+FF5E). The first of these is [CJK_Symbols](http://codepoints.net/search?blk=CJK_Symbols) block, which appears not to be present in all Unicode fonts, such as on Android. However, the second is in the [Half_And_Full_Forms](http://codepoints.net/search?blk=Half_And_Full_Forms) block, which does appear to be present, and a quick test on my Android phone with the standard Japanese IME confirms that `U+FF5E FULLWIDTH TILDE` is used.

Now, you mention that you are encoding UTF-8 - perhaps there is an error in the conversion tables you are using? I would recommend that you just silently replace all instances of `U+301C WAVE DASH` with `U+FF5E FULLWIDTH TILDE`.

**UPDATE**: You mention your translator - perhaps they are using a Mac, which appears to prefer the `U+301C WAVE DASH`? Furthermore, here is [a WordPress plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/force-wave-dash/) that suggests a few more characters that should be tested, although I suspect that the tilde/wave dash will be the only problem.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth info! We tried changing type faces (sanserif, serif, etc) no go. It's unfortunate, but we'll replace the wave dashes with tildes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The boxes indicate that the font set doesn't have that character. That ~ is how young Japanese are writing the chouon (vowel doubler "ー"). The よ is yo. Formally you'd write よー if the o sound should be held for a additional beat.

If the chouon is in the font, you could correct it for them.

I'm on Linux right now and when I switch to Japanese it gives me 〜 for the tilde.

**EDIT**
Suddenly realized that I could use the character map to find what that was. It is the U+301C wavy dash.

This is from my Nexus 7. よ~!

And that was a regular tilde. Best of luck. Wish I could have been more help.

Comment: Perhaps this should be x-posted to japanese.stackexchange, but ～　is not just what the kids are using, but a real mark that indicates tremolo in the extended vowel, as I seem to remember a TV show mentioning. Furthermore, it's often used as shorthand for indicating a span of time, like 12:00～17:00, so "autocorrecting" it would probably annoy people!

Comment: That would probably help the question poster a lot. I'm American and my Japanese is very poor.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is a very interesting explanation. I don't know Japanese so I would feel uncomfortable changing the text. I'll take a look at U+301C.

Comment: BTW, how did you type your ~? I can copy-paste your 〜, but on Windows and Opera my 〜 gets changed to a ～...

Comment: On my linux machine I'm using SCIM as my input method and switching to japanese. On my Nexus 7 I was using iWnn IME.